# How to fix a permissions problem on www folder?

Tags: permissions, apache2, webserver

I have created a directory in my `www` folder using terminal and `root` user.
Then, create some text files in that folder (with terminal and `root` user).

Now, when I want to access these files and directory via browser, Apache said:

> 403 Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /folder on this server.

Other files and folders in `www` directory are accessible via browser (I uploaded them via FTP client).

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

run this command in the terminal after navigating to www folder:

```
    sudo chmod 755 *
```

Answer (score 0):

The webserver must have privilieges to read the files and directories in this webserver-root-directory.
Make sure the permissions are 644 (or higer if required) and owned by www-data:www-data or your FTP-User if this work for your setup.

Try to delete your browser-cache if the error is still shown.

Comment: folder is set to `755`, and files are `644`. I tried this command: `chown www-data:www-data folder`, but it said: `invalid user: www-data`

Comment: Did you installed apache from apt? It should create a user and a group called "www-data". What does `id www-data` say? Take a look in "/etc/apache2/envvars" What is set for `export APACHE_RUN_USER` and `export APACHE_RUN_GROUP`? Try to chown your files to this user and group.